# Flume memory channel consumes disk space

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, syslog, flume

I am running a flume agent which uses memory channel.

```
agent.channels.c1.type = memory
agent.channels.c1.capacity = 1000000
```

Source is of the type `syslogtcp` and sink if of the type `hdfs`. The agent is collecting about 1 million records every minute.

The concern I am having is that, my flume agent consumes disk space even though I am using memory channel. So if my agent is running for about a month, it uses around 300gb of my disk space which is causing the issue. So the questions are

**Q1:** Why disk space is consumed when running this agent which uses memory channel?

**Q2:** When will this space be released? Is there any conditions or should it be done manually.? Any idea which will be the location these files will be stored?

Answer (score 0):

How big are the documents? The typical block size in HDFS is 64MB, sometimes set to 128MB... so if you have a 2k doc, it still takes 64MB on disk!!!

You should set the 'batchsize' parameter to a high number to batch these events into larger files on HDFS. 
Of course that will also alter the speed at which the events are dumps on HDFS and the jobs after that so if you're after real time, this is not ideal. Instead of sinking to HDFS you might want to sink to HBase instead, which aggregates smaller events into a big table.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my files are getting created at a size of ~350mb i.e., once the roll count has reached. But how will this take up 300gb of data over period? if we assume, flume is storing it in disk for temporary purpose, still it should take up only 350mb not gbs.